# При регистрации в базе данных ничего не появляется

Tags: php, mysqli

Не работает регистрация в PHP, выводит "Hi", но в базе данных ничего не появляется.

```php
<?php
   $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),
 FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $password2 = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']),
 FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     if(mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90){
        echo "Не допустимая длинна логина";
        exit();
     }
     else if(mb_strlen($password) < 5){
        echo "Не допустимая длинна пароля";

     }
     else if($password !== $password2){
         echo "Пароли не совпадают!";
     }
     else{
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','users');
        if($connection == false){
            echo "BAD(";
        }
        else{
        echo('Hi');
        $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','users');
        $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `email`)
        VALUES('$login', '$password', '$password2')");

        $mysql -> close();
     }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе о действии трех разных видов кавычек в PHP? Надо вот так `VALUES('".$login."',`

Comment: Советую использовать PDO вместо mysqli

Comment: Два раза к базе коннектиться зачем? Чтобы уж наверняка?

Comment: Емейл это пароль2? Где же логика?

Comment: @becouse, ну раз вы вкурсе про 3 вида кавычек, почему не сморите, что родительские кавычки это двойные, а между двойных, переменные можно обрабатывать без конкатенации.

Comment: @And так не работает же)

Comment: @becouse, ну уж явно не из-за кавычек проблема, скорее всего проблема в соединениях или еще чего. ЛОГИ читать мысленно не умею.

Comment: Написать что-то подобное

$result = mysql->query(...
if (!$result) {
    echo('Неверный запрос');
}

Потому что не факт что запрос выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в строке

```
$password !== $password2
```

сравниваются пароль и емэйл) судя по названию переменной.

тоже определитесь с email и я вам указал как верно ковычки использовать в данном случае.

```
 VALUES('".$login."', '".$password."', '".$password2."')");
```

Ну и не выбрана сама база данных, должен быть 4ый параметр с указанием названия базы данных

```
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','users', 'my_db');
```

Советую проверить подключение к базе и соответствие названиям столбцов в БД и указанных в INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Используемые ссылки на документацию:

- [isset()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) - Определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением, отличным от NULL
- [in_array()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) - Проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве значение
- [strlen()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php) - Возвращает длину строки
- [(!==)](https://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php) - Операторы сравнения
- [exit()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exit.php) - Вывести сообщение и прекратить выполнение текущего скрипта
- [try() catch()](https://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php) - Исключения
- [new mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) - Улучшенный модуль MySQL
- [mysqli::$connect_error](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.connect-error.php) - Возвращает описание последней ошибки подключения
- [mysqli::$connect_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.connect-errno.php) - Возвращает код ошибки последней попытки соединения
- [mysqli::prepare](https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) - Подготавливает SQL выражение к выполнению
- [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) - Привязка переменных к параметрам подготавливаемого запроса
- [mysqli_stmt::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) - Выполняет подготовленный запрос
- [mysqli_stmt::close](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.close.php) - Закрывает подготовленный запрос
- [error_log()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php) - Отправляет сообщение об ошибке заданному обработчику ошибок

---

```
<?php

// https://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php
$login      = isset($_POST['login']) ? trim($_POST['login']) : null;
$email      = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;
$password2  = isset($_POST['password-confirm']) ? trim($_POST['password-confirm']) : null;

// Проверяется заполнение каждых из значений - https://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php
if (in_array(null, [$login, $email, $password, $password2]))
    exit("Одно из полей не было заполнено");

// Проверяется длина переменной - https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php
if (strlen($login) < 5 || strlen($login) > 90)
    exit("Длина логина не должна быть меньше 5 и больше 90 символов.");


// Проверяется длина переменной - https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php
if (strlen($email) < 5 || strlen($email) > 90)
    exit("Длина почты не должна быть меньше 5 и больше 90 символов.");


// Проверяется длина переменной - https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php
if (strlen($password) < 5 || strlen($password) > 90)
    exit("Длина пароля не должна быть меньше 5 и больше 90 символов.");

// Подтверждение пароля, обязательно через !== - https://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php
if ($password !== $password2)
    exit("Пароли не совпадают.");


// https://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php
try {

    // new mysqli('хост', 'логин', 'пароль', 'название базы данных');
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test');

    // Если ловим ошибку, выбрасываем исключение
    if ($mysqli->connect_error || $mysqli->connect_errno)
        throw new Exception("Connect Error ({$mysqli->connect_errno}) {$mysqli->connect_error}");

    // Устанавливаем кодировку
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");

} catch(Exception $e) {

    // https://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php
    error_log($e->getMessage());

    // https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exit.php
    exit($e->getMessage());

}

// Запрос, имеет 3 вопросительных знака на конце, именно к ним и будут привязываться данные
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `email`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

// Подготовка запроса - https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php
if (!$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql))
{
    echo "Ошибка подготовки запроса: {$query->error}" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Номер ошибки: {$query->errno}";
    exit();
}

// Привязка данных к подготовленному запросу - https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
// Первый аргумент указывает на тип данных которые будут заполняться - s - строка.
if (!$query->bind_param('sss', $login, $password, $email))
{
    echo "Ошибка привязки данных: {$query->error}" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Номер ошибки: {$query->errno}";
    exit();
}

// Выполнение запроса - https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
if (!$query->execute()) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: {$query->error}" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Номер ошибки: {$query->errno}";
    exit();
}

// Если дальше нет никакого кода, можно закрыть соединение с базой данных.
```